# How to put math symbol higher up in text?

Tags: positioning

[image: culprit]

Hello,

I was wondering how I could put the infinity symbol a bit higher up so that it does not look akward compared to the € symbol ? I was thinking it may be nicer if the infinity symbol was aligned in the middle of the text line but I don't know how I can do that and I have found no post talking about that.
Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: In general, `\vcenter{\hbox{$\infty$}}` would place the `\infty` vertically centered about the math axis.  However, that may or may not be enough of a shift for you.  The other option is `\raisebox`.

Comment: \raisebox{0.15ex}{$\infty$} does the trick :) Thank you